# What does ${1+"$@"} mean in a unix shell script?

Tags: sh

I came across this construct while reviewing some older unix shell scripts, what does it mean, and why is is used?

```
${1+"$@"}
```

Comment: What did the documentation say about it?

Comment: [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) Important sentence that is easy to miss: "Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset."

Comment: Thanks!  I found it hard to search google (or even stackoverflow) with such constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this explanation from unix haters handbook, page 152 of text (page 190 of the pdf). http://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf

It’s the way to exactly reproduce the command line arguments in the
/bin/sh family of shells shell script.

It says, “If there is at least one argument ( ${1+ ), then substitute in
all the arguments ( “$@” ) preserving all the spaces, etc. within each
argument.

If we used only “$@” then that would substitute to “” (a null argument)
if there were no invocation arguments, but we want no arguments reproduced in
that case, not “”.

Why not “$*” etc.? From a sh(1) man page:

Inside a pair of double quote marks (“”), parameter and
command substitution occurs and the shell quotes the results to
avoid blank interpretation and file name generation. If $* is
within a pair of double quotes, the positional parameters are
substituted and quoted, separated by quoted spaces (“$1
$2 …”); however, if $@ is within a pair of double quotes, the
positional parameters are substituted and quoted, separated by
unquoted spaces (“$1” “$2” …).

I think ${1+“$@”} is portable all the way back to “Version 7 Unix.”

Wow! All the way back to Version 7.

Comment: It seems you don't get the "null argument" in modern sh: <linebreak>
/bin/sh -c '/bin/sh -c "echo \$#" -- "$@"' -- <linebreak>
0

Answer (score 0):

Google should be your best friend! This is a similar questions asked almost 2 years ago.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/what-does-1-mean-in-a-shell-script-and-how-does-it-differ-from